# Table components not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am creating a work schedule site and am fairly new to react.

I can call the renderEmployeeRota function from inside the main render JSX, and what it returns is rendered onto the site. However, anything I try to render from the RotaEntry component is completely ignored.

I cannot figure out why the component isn't being rendered, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

`

```
export default class RotaEntry extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    <td>This isn't being rendered?</td>
  }
}
```

```
renderEmployeeRota() {
    return this.state.employees.map((employee) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{employee.employee_id}</td>
          <td>{employee.employee_name}</td>
          <RotaEntry employeeId={employee.employee_id} date={this.state.currentWeek} />
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
```

`

Comment: you are missing return statement in render lifecycle

Comment: unbelievably embarrased, ive been looking at this for ages trying to figure this out lol

Comment: it happens. You might have learned a lot of other stuff while doing rnd for this bug :p

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Reactjs documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) the simplest form of a class based component looks like this:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
  }
}
```

As you can see the `render` method should return a `JSX` element. **The render method in `RotaEntry` does not return anything!** This is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to return a value from your **render**

```js
export default class RotaEntry extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <td>This isn't being rendered?</td>
  }


}
```

Or Better still use a functional component

```js
const Rotary =(props)=> <div>Your Code Here </div>
```